# Android - Remove completely ActionBar Sherlock (ABS) from project

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've implemented **ActionBar Sherlock** in my project, but now i would prefer to replace it with a simple custom layout bar and remove ABS completely from my project. I've googled it and couldn't find anything similar to this. I remember when i implemented ABS that i have deleted the default @libs. How do i completely remove it and implement back the previous stuff without messing up? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, let your MainActivity extends Activity instead of SherlockActivity..and then right click on your project goto properties->Andrioid..scroll down and remove ABS library and apply..In manifest if u have applied any theme then change it to @style/AppTheme..and that should be it..

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. In addition to removing the ABS Library and extending MainActivity from Activity instead of SherlockActivity... you have to make sure all of your activities are switched. You also have to make change fragments as well. Any imports you have need to be changed as well (ActionBar, Menu, MenuItem, etc). I'd suggest in a separate branch deleting ABS and see where the errors are and go from there.